# Is there a name for a boolean operator whose value always equals its left-hand side operand?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, binary-operations

Given a binary boolean function with truth table as follows:

```
|-----------|
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
|---|---|---|
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
|---|---|---| 
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
|---|---|---| 
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
|-----------|
```

I am wondering if this function has a name in academia?

Comment: Are you asking for the name of $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1$? (assuming the digits are ordered left to right)

Comment: That's correct @mjw

Comment: Yes, I saw the name sometime, somewhere.  Another name is $x_1$ (or was that the name?!).

Comment: I suppose one could call it a projection onto the first argument.

Comment: "Left projection"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general $f(x_1, x_2) = x_1$ is called "projection onto the first factor."

Answer (score 1):

Projection or identity.

In general, a function that returns the $m$-th of its $n$ arguments is written as $id^n_m$

So your boolean function would be would be $id^2_1$, and thus $id^2_1(P,Q)=P$